# Hotspot is invisible

Tags: networking, 18.04, hot-spot

Installed Ubuntu 18.04 . When I turn on Hotspot ,it's open as normal.but when I search for this Hotspot in my mobile , I am not able to see it or connect it. I have tried various methods , created new Hotspot connection, but Hotspot is invisible when I look in my mobile. When I use a live usb and turn the Hotspot on , it shows in my mobile ,and I was able to connect but in the installed os  no hotspot

Comment: Is the connection discoverable? What about the WiFi? Is it working fine? It may happen that due to incorrect driver/settings the range is very low that other devices can't find that. What is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 0280`?

Comment: @Kulfy Wifi is working. Connection is not discoverable in my mobile , ubuntu shows 'network name' ' security type' and password as usual when Hotspot is on but I can't see any network in mobile.                                                                  ...   Network controller [0280] Realtek semiconductor co Ltd . RTL8822BE ........wifi adaptor. / Subsystem azurewave device / kernel driver in use rtw_pci/ kernal module rtwpci --- is shown when lspci -nnk | grep - A3 0280 is written

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Edit the hotspot configuration file.**

```
This is done by going to the System menu and selecting: Wi-Fi Off > Turn On
Next, select Wi-Fi Settings
In the Wi-Fi Settings window, click on the Gnome menu icon from the window upper right-hand side corner, and select Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot:
```

**Option 2: NM Connection Editor.**

```
You can start it by pressing Alt + F2
And type: nm-connection-editor
```

And then restart the service
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

[How To Create A Wi-Fi Hotspot In Ubuntu 18.04 / Gnome (And Edit Its Settings)](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/how-to-create-wi-fi-hotspot-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: I you are going to spam the exact same answer across multiple questions, you should at least try to get the formatting correct. Thanks. https://askubuntu.com/a/1219838/106495 https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/1026019

Answer (score 0):

If by `hotspot is invisible` you mean `greyed out`, then I have a perfectly clean solution for you.

So I had this problem where I could not `turn on wifi hotspot`. The option was always greyed out. After some frustration and a little bit of research, I came across this neat trick.

I assume you are in the settings, the `wifi` tab. Just select the `network` tab, then go back to the `wifi` tab. Now in the options you will see `turn on wifi hotspot`, this time not greyed out.

It's just a small bug, and not knowing this small fix can completely ruin your day. Hope this helps.